# get stream list of all users in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

i'm using the javascript getstream integration library: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js.

I've configured a user feed on my getstream dashboard, suppose i add few users as `user:test1` `user:test2` `user:test3`. Is there any way that i can get list of all users that are registered on the user feed group.

Similarly i want this to work for news updates posted by user, where he can see list of users and can follow them.

Comment: don't you store users in your own database?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli i'm saving my own users in my own database, but my approach was a bit different as i didn't want processing to be done on various side........



because getstream already provides an end point to see that how many user's i'm following......
so it would have been simple if i could just get an endpoint from getstream and process it on my nodeJS server and finally just provide the client an JSON which needs to be rendered.

Comment: from a product perspective, why do you need to show a list of feeds and how do you select the feeds to display to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to list all the feeds created on a certain feed group via API. You are responsible to store the users of your application within your own backend.